# java: String concat in bytecode converted to StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, jvm, stringbuilder, javap

I reviewed my compiled code with javac command line and I saw whenever I used String concatenation with + operator, compiled code replaced with StringBuilder's append() method.
now I think  using StringBuilder and String concatenation have same performance because they have similar bytecode, is it correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, it is true! But when you concatenate in loop the behaviour differs. e.g.

```
String str = "Some string";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  str += i;
}
```

new `StringBuilder` will be constructed at every single loop iteration (with initial value of str) and at the end of every iteration there will be concatenation with initial String (actually `StringBuilder` with initial value of `str`).
So you need to create StringBuilder by yourself only when you work with String concatenation in loop.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference (and the reason the compiler uses `StringBuilder` for string concatenation) is that `String` is immutable, whereas `StringBuilder` isn't.

For example, computing `s1 + s2 + s3` using strings alone would require `s1`'s characters to be copied twice. This can be (and is) avoided by using `StringBuilder`.

This optimization is explicitly permitted by the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.